# Проблемы с загрузкой файла c внешнего IP адреса, используя ttorrent библиотеку

Tags: java, ip, vds, torrent

Добрый вечер! Столкнулся с проблемой загрузки файлов с внешнего IP-адреса, используя данную торрент библиотек — [ttorent](https://github.com/mpetazzoni/ttorrent).

---

Собственно, проблема заключается в следующем: если я устанавливаю для трекера локальный адрес (`127.0.0.1` или `192.168.1.101`) в качестве используемого, тогда загрузка файла на этом же компьютере работает хорошо. Однако, если я использую мой VDS-компьютер с внешним адресом, тогда дела куда печальнее и загрузка не работает.

---

Код трекера, где добавляются файлы на загрузку и включается один сид:

```
public final class TorrentTracker {
    public static final int TORRENT_TRACKER_PORT = 7816;

    private Map<Integer, Pair<Torrent, Client>> torrentFilesMap;
    private IApplicationNetworkRepository networkRepository;
    private Tracker torrentTracker;
    private boolean isWorking;

    public TorrentTracker(IApplicationNetworkRepository networkRepository) throws IOException {
        this.torrentFilesMap = new HashMap<>();

        this.networkRepository = networkRepository;
        this.torrentTracker = new Tracker(new InetSocketAddress(
                networkRepository.getExternalIpAddress(),
                TORRENT_TRACKER_PORT));
        this.torrentFilesMap = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public void addFileForSharing(File sharedFile)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, URISyntaxException {
        Torrent torrent = generateTorrent(sharedFile);
        torrentTracker.announce(new TrackedTorrent(torrent));

        //Without, at minimum, one seed - we can't share file
        Client torrentClient = new Client(
                new InetSocketAddress(
                        networkRepository.getExternalIpAddress(),
                        TORRENT_TRACKER_PORT).getAddress(),
                new SharedTorrent(torrent, sharedFile.getParentFile()));
        torrentClient.share();

        torrentFilesMap.put(sharedFile.hashCode(), new Pair<>(torrent, torrentClient));
    }

    public void removeSharedFile(File sharedFile) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        torrentFilesMap.get(sharedFile.hashCode()).getRightValue().stop();
        torrentTracker.remove(torrentFilesMap.get(sharedFile.hashCode()).getLeftValue());
        torrentFilesMap.remove(sharedFile.hashCode());
    }

    public Torrent getTorrentForFile(File sharingFile) {
        return torrentFilesMap.get(sharingFile.hashCode()).getLeftValue();
    }

    public void start() {
        isWorking = true;
        torrentTracker.start();
    }

    public void stop() {
        isWorking = false;
        torrentTracker.stop();
    }

    public boolean isWorking() {
        return isWorking;
    }

    public String getTrackerIp() {
        return torrentTracker.getAnnounceUrl().getHost();
    }

    private Torrent generateTorrent(File fileForShare) throws IOException, URISyntaxException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InterruptedException {
        //Current realisation of torrent tracker returns canonical host address as tracker address. In case, when
        //user uses domain as tracker host, canonical address can return address of internet provider instead. So,
        //we use specific address, which user inputted manually
        URL announceUrlWithIncorrectHost = torrentTracker.getAnnounceUrl();
        URL announceUrl = new URL(announceUrlWithIncorrectHost.toString().replace(
                torrentTracker.getAnnounceUrl().getHost(),
                networkRepository.getExternalIpAddress()));
        return TrackedTorrent.create(fileForShare, announceUrl.toURI(), "null");
    }
}
```

Код метода загрузки (до этого торрент сохраняется в торрент-файл):

```
public void downloadTorrentFile(File torrentFile,
                                    String destFolder,
                                    DownloadStartListener downloadStartListener,
                                    DownloadProgressListener downloadProgressListener) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        Torrent torrent = Torrent.load(torrentFile);
        prepareFolderForDownloading(torrent.getFilenames(), new File(destFolder));

        InetAddress localHost = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        SharedTorrent sharedTorrent = SharedTorrent.fromFile(torrentFile, new File(destFolder));
        Client client = new Client(localHost, sharedTorrent);

        client.addObserver((observable, data) -> {
            Client torrentClient = (Client) observable;
            downloadProgressListener.onProgressChanged(torrentClient.getTorrent().getCompletion());
        });

        downloadStartListener.onStartListener(torrent.getFilenames().toArray(new String[torrent.getFilenames().size()]));
        client.download();
        client.waitForCompletion();
    }
```

---

Лог трекера при успешной загрузке по локальному адресу (прошу прощения, если попал лишний лог, я старался не убрать ничего лишнего):

```
com.turn.ttorrent.common.Torrent - Creating single-file torrent for disk_image_1...
com.turn.ttorrent.common.Torrent - Hashing data from disk_image_1 with 4 threads (1 pieces)...
com.turn.ttorrent.common.Torrent -   ... 10% complete
com.turn.ttorrent.common.Torrent - Hashed 1 file(s) (397 bytes) in 1 pieces (1 expected) in 23,8ms.
com.turn.ttorrent.common.Torrent - Single-file torrent information:
com.turn.ttorrent.common.Torrent -   Torrent name: disk_image_1
com.turn.ttorrent.common.Torrent -   Announced at:
com.turn.ttorrent.common.Torrent -      1. http://127.0.0.1:7816/announce
com.turn.ttorrent.common.Torrent -   Created on..: Fri Aug 04 01:30:10 MSK 2017
com.turn.ttorrent.common.Torrent -   Created by..: null
com.turn.ttorrent.common.Torrent -   Pieces......: 1 piece(s) (524288 byte(s)/piece)
com.turn.ttorrent.common.Torrent -   Total size..: 397 byte(s)
com.turn.ttorrent.common.Torrent - Single-file torrent information:
com.turn.ttorrent.common.Torrent -   Torrent name: disk_image_1
com.turn.ttorrent.common.Torrent -   Announced at:
com.turn.ttorrent.common.Torrent -      1. http://127.0.0.1:7816/announce
com.turn.ttorrent.common.Torrent -   Created on..: Fri Aug 04 01:30:10 MSK 2017
com.turn.ttorrent.common.Torrent -   Created by..: null
com.turn.ttorrent.common.Torrent -   Pieces......: 1 piece(s) (524288 byte(s)/piece)
com.turn.ttorrent.common.Torrent -   Total size..: 397 byte(s)
com.turn.ttorrent.tracker.Tracker - Registered new torrent for 'disk_image_1' with hash d868a20e77b1833733b3abe840e82d8cf24c5ca3.
com.turn.ttorrent.common.Torrent - Single-file torrent information:
com.turn.ttorrent.common.Torrent -   Torrent name: disk_image_1
com.turn.ttorrent.common.Torrent -   Announced at:
com.turn.ttorrent.common.Torrent -      1. http://127.0.0.1:7816/announce
com.turn.ttorrent.common.Torrent -   Created on..: Fri Aug 04 01:30:10 MSK 2017
com.turn.ttorrent.common.Torrent -   Created by..: null
com.turn.ttorrent.common.Torrent -   Pieces......: 1 piece(s) (524288 byte(s)/piece)
com.turn.ttorrent.common.Torrent -   Total size..: 397 byte(s)
c.t.t.client.storage.FileStorage - Using existing file D:\Development\Projects\OSLoader\OSLoaderServer\target\data\disk_image_1.
c.t.t.client.storage.FileStorage - Initialized byte storage file at D:\Development\Projects\OSLoader\OSLoaderServer\target\data\disk_image_1 (0+397 byte(s)).
c.t.t.c.s.FileCollectionStorage - Initialized torrent byte storage on 1 file(s) (397 total byte(s)).
c.t.t.client.ConnectionHandler - Listening for incoming connections on /127.0.0.1:49152.
c.t.t.client.announce.Announce - Initialized announce sub-system with 1 trackers on disk_image_1.
com.turn.ttorrent.client.Client - BitTorrent client [..326131] for disk_image_1 started and listening at 127.0.0.1:49152...
c.t.ttorrent.client.SharedTorrent - Analyzing local data for disk_image_1 with 4 threads (1 pieces)...
c.t.ttorrent.client.SharedTorrent - disk_image_1: we have 397/397 bytes (100,0%) [1/1 pieces].
com.turn.ttorrent.client.Client - Download of 1 pieces completed.
com.turn.ttorrent.client.Client - Seeding indefinetely...
c.t.t.client.announce.Announce - Starting announce loop...
com.turn.ttorrent.client.Client - SEEDING 1/1 pieces (100,00%) [0/0] with 0/0 peers at 0,00/0,00 kB/s.
c.t.t.c.announce.HTTPTrackerClient - Announcing STARTED to tracker with 0U/0D/0L bytes...
c.t.t.client.announce.Announce - No response or unreachable tracker!
com.turn.ttorrent.tracker.Tracker - Starting BitTorrent tracker on http://127.0.0.1:7816/announce...
com.turn.ttorrent.tracker.Tracker - Starting tracker peer collection for tracker at http://127.0.0.1:7816/announce...
com.turn.ttorrent.client.Client - SEEDING 1/1 pieces (100,00%) [0/0] with 0/0 peers at 0,00/0,00 kB/s.
com.turn.ttorrent.client.Client - SEEDING 1/1 pieces (100,00%) [0/0] with 0/0 peers at 0,00/0,00 kB/s.
c.t.t.c.announce.HTTPTrackerClient - Announcing STARTED to tracker with 0U/0D/0L bytes...
c.turn.ttorrent.tracker.TrackedPeer - Peer peer://127.0.0.1:49152/326131 completed download of disk_image_1.
c.t.t.client.announce.Announce - Setting announce interval to 10s per tracker request.
c.turn.ttorrent.tracker.TrackedPeer - Peer peer://192.168.233.2:49152/313831 started download of disk_image_1.
c.t.t.client.ConnectionHandler - New incoming connection, waiting for handshake...
com.turn.ttorrent.client.Client - Handling new peer connection with peer://127.0.0.1:49546/313831...
c.t.t.client.peer.PeerExchange - Started peer exchange with peer://127.0.0.1:49546/313831 [Ci|Ci|0] for disk_image_1.
com.turn.ttorrent.client.Client - New peer connection with peer://127.0.0.1:49546/313831 [Ci|Ci|0] [1/2].
com.turn.ttorrent.client.Client - SEEDING 1/1 pieces (100,00%) [0/0] with 1/2 peers at 0,00/0,00 kB/s.
com.turn.ttorrent.client.Client -   | peer://127.0.0.1:49546/313831 [CI|ci|0] 
c.turn.ttorrent.tracker.TrackedPeer - Peer peer://192.168.233.2:49152/313831 completed download of disk_image_1.
c.turn.ttorrent.tracker.TrackedPeer - Peer peer://192.168.233.2:49152/313831 stopped download of disk_image_1.
c.t.t.client.peer.PeerExchange - Could not read message from peer://127.0.0.1:49546/313831 [CI|ci|1]: Unexpected end-of-stream while reading
c.t.t.client.peer.PeerExchange - Peer exchange with peer://127.0.0.1:49546/313831 [CI|ci|1] closed.
com.turn.ttorrent.client.Client - Peer peer://127.0.0.1:49546/313831 [CI|ci|1] disconnected, [0/2].
c.t.ttorrent.client.SharedTorrent - Peer peer://127.0.0.1:49546/313831 [Ci|Ci|1] went away with 1 piece(s) [completed=1; available=0/1]
c.turn.ttorrent.tracker.TrackedPeer - Peer peer://192.168.233.2:49152/396262 completed download of disk_image_1.
com.turn.ttorrent.client.Client - SEEDING 1/1 pieces (100,00%) [0/0] with 0/2 peers at 0,00/0,00 kB/s.
com.turn.ttorrent.client.Client - SEEDING 1/1 pieces (100,00%) [0/0] with 0/2 peers at 0,00/0,00 kB/s.
c.t.t.c.announce.HTTPTrackerClient - Announcing to tracker with 397U/0D/0L bytes...
com.turn.ttorrent.client.Client - Got 1 peer(s) in tracker response.
```

Лог трекера при не успешной загрузке (обратите внимание на обрыв загрузки):

```
com.turn.ttorrent.common.Torrent - Creating single-file torrent for disk_image_1...
com.turn.ttorrent.common.Torrent - Hashing data from disk_image_1 with 1 threads (1 pieces)...
com.turn.ttorrent.common.Torrent -   ... 10% complete
com.turn.ttorrent.common.Torrent - Hashed 1 file(s) (397 bytes) in 1 pieces (1 expected) in 14.8ms.
com.turn.ttorrent.common.Torrent - Single-file torrent information:
com.turn.ttorrent.common.Torrent -   Torrent name: disk_image_1
com.turn.ttorrent.common.Torrent -   Announced at:
com.turn.ttorrent.common.Torrent -      1. http://rostislav.dugin.xyz:7816/announce
com.turn.ttorrent.common.Torrent -   Created on..: Fri Aug 04 01:44:37 MSK 2017
com.turn.ttorrent.common.Torrent -   Created by..: null
com.turn.ttorrent.common.Torrent -   Pieces......: 1 piece(s) (524288 byte(s)/piece)
com.turn.ttorrent.common.Torrent -   Total size..: 397 byte(s)
com.turn.ttorrent.common.Torrent - Single-file torrent information:
com.turn.ttorrent.common.Torrent -   Torrent name: disk_image_1
com.turn.ttorrent.common.Torrent -   Announced at:
com.turn.ttorrent.common.Torrent -      1. http://rostislav.dugin.xyz:7816/announce
com.turn.ttorrent.common.Torrent -   Created on..: Fri Aug 04 01:44:37 MSK 2017
com.turn.ttorrent.common.Torrent -   Created by..: null
com.turn.ttorrent.common.Torrent -   Pieces......: 1 piece(s) (524288 byte(s)/piece)
com.turn.ttorrent.common.Torrent -   Total size..: 397 byte(s)
com.turn.ttorrent.tracker.Tracker - Registered new torrent for 'disk_image_1' with hash d868a20e77b1833733b3abe840e82d8cf24c5ca3.
com.turn.ttorrent.common.Torrent - Single-file torrent information:
com.turn.ttorrent.common.Torrent -   Torrent name: disk_image_1
com.turn.ttorrent.common.Torrent -   Announced at:
com.turn.ttorrent.common.Torrent -      1. http://rostislav.dugin.xyz:7816/announce
com.turn.ttorrent.common.Torrent -   Created on..: Fri Aug 04 01:44:37 MSK 2017
com.turn.ttorrent.common.Torrent -   Created by..: null
com.turn.ttorrent.common.Torrent -   Pieces......: 1 piece(s) (524288 byte(s)/piece)
com.turn.ttorrent.common.Torrent -   Total size..: 397 byte(s)
c.t.t.client.storage.FileStorage - Using existing file /opt/application/OSLoader/data/disk_image_1.
c.t.t.client.storage.FileStorage - Initialized byte storage file at /opt/application/OSLoader/data/disk_image_1 (0+397 byte(s)).
c.t.t.c.s.FileCollectionStorage - Initialized torrent byte storage on 1 file(s) (397 total byte(s)).
c.t.t.client.ConnectionHandler - Listening for incoming connections on rostislav.dugin.xyz/37.46.135.189:49152.
c.t.t.client.announce.Announce - Initialized announce sub-system with 1 trackers on disk_image_1.
com.turn.ttorrent.client.Client - BitTorrent client [..623339] for disk_image_1 started and listening at 37.46.135.189:49152...
c.t.ttorrent.client.SharedTorrent - Analyzing local data for disk_image_1 with 1 threads (1 pieces)...
c.t.ttorrent.client.SharedTorrent - disk_image_1: we have 397/397 bytes (100.0%) [1/1 pieces].
com.turn.ttorrent.client.Client - Download of 1 pieces completed.
com.turn.ttorrent.client.Client - Seeding indefinetely...
com.turn.ttorrent.client.Client - SEEDING 1/1 pieces (100.00%) [0/0] with 0/0 peers at 0.00/0.00 kB/s.
c.t.t.client.announce.Announce - Starting announce loop...
c.t.t.c.announce.HTTPTrackerClient - Announcing STARTED to tracker with 0U/0D/0L bytes...
c.t.t.client.announce.Announce - No response or unreachable tracker!
com.turn.ttorrent.tracker.Tracker - Starting BitTorrent tracker on http://rostislav.dugin.fvds.ru:7816/announce...
com.turn.ttorrent.tracker.Tracker - Starting tracker peer collection for tracker at http://rostislav.dugin.fvds.ru:7816/announce...
org.xnio - XNIO version 3.3.6.Finalcom.turn.ttorrent.client.Client - SEEDING 1/1 pieces (100.00%) [0/0] with 0/0 peers at 0.00/0.00 kB/s.
c.t.t.c.announce.HTTPTrackerClient - Announcing STARTED to tracker with 0U/0D/0L bytes...
c.turn.ttorrent.tracker.TrackedPeer - Peer peer://37.46.135.189:49152/623339 completed download of disk_image_1.
c.t.t.client.announce.Announce - Setting announce interval to 10s per tracker request.
com.turn.ttorrent.client.Client - SEEDING 1/1 pieces (100.00%) [0/0] with 0/0 peers at 0.00/0.00 kB/s.
com.turn.ttorrent.client.Client - SEEDING 1/1 pieces (100.00%) [0/0] with 0/0 peers at 0.00/0.00 kB/s.
com.turn.ttorrent.client.Client - SEEDING 1/1 pieces (100.00%) [0/0] with 0/0 peers at 0.00/0.00 kB/s.
com.turn.ttorrent.client.Client - SEEDING 1/1 pieces (100.00%) [0/0] with 0/0 peers at 0.00/0.00 kB/s.
c.t.t.c.announce.HTTPTrackerClient - Announcing to tracker with 0U/0D/0L bytes...
com.turn.ttorrent.client.Client - SEEDING 1/1 pieces (100.00%) [0/0] with 0/0 peers at 0.00/0.00 kB/s.
com.turn.ttorrent.client.Client - SEEDING 1/1 pieces (100.00%) [0/0] with 0/0 peers at 0.00/0.00 kB/s.
com.turn.ttorrent.client.Client - SEEDING 1/1 pieces (100.00%) [0/0] with 0/0 peers at 0.00/0.00 kB/s.
c.t.t.c.announce.HTTPTrackerClient - Announcing to tracker with 0U/0D/0L bytes...
com.turn.ttorrent.client.Client - SEEDING 1/1 pieces (100.00%) [0/0] with 0/0 peers at 0.00/0.00 kB/s.
com.turn.ttorrent.client.Client - SEEDING 1/1 pieces (100.00%) [0/0] with 0/0 peers at 0.00/0.00 kB/s.
com.turn.ttorrent.client.Client - SEEDING 1/1 pieces (100.00%) [0/0] with 0/0 peers at 0.00/0.00 kB/s.
c.t.t.c.announce.HTTPTrackerClient - Announcing to tracker with 0U/0D/0L bytes...
com.turn.ttorrent.client.Client - SEEDING 1/1 pieces (100.00%) [0/0] with 0/0 peers at 0.00/0.00 kB/s.
c.turn.ttorrent.tracker.TrackedPeer - Peer peer://192.168.233.2:49152/636465 started download of disk_image_1.
com.turn.ttorrent.client.Client - SEEDING 1/1 pieces (100.00%) [0/0] with 0/0 peers at 0.00/0.00 kB/s.
com.turn.ttorrent.client.Client - SEEDING 1/1 pieces (100.00%) [0/0] with 0/0 peers at 0.00/0.00 kB/s.
c.t.t.c.announce.HTTPTrackerClient - Announcing to tracker with 0U/0D/0L bytes...
com.turn.ttorrent.client.Client - Got 1 peer(s) in tracker response.
io.undertow.request.io - Error reading request
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)
    at org.xnio.nio.NioSocketConduit.read(NioSocketConduit.java:286)
    at org.xnio.conduits.ConduitStreamSourceChannel.read(ConduitStreamSourceChannel.java:127)
    at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpReadListener.handleEventWithNoRunningRequest(HttpReadListener.java:153)
    at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpReadListener.handleEvent(HttpReadListener.java:131)
    at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpReadListener.handleEvent(HttpReadListener.java:57)
    at org.xnio.ChannelListeners.invokeChannelListener(ChannelListeners.java:92)
    at org.xnio.conduits.ReadReadyHandler$ChannelListenerHandler.readReady(ReadReadyHandler.java:66)
    at org.xnio.nio.NioSocketConduit.handleReady(NioSocketConduit.java:88)
    at org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:559)
com.turn.ttorrent.client.Client - SEEDING 1/1 pieces (100.00%) [0/0] with 0/1 peers at 0.00/0.00 kB/s.
com.turn.ttorrent.client.Client - SEEDING 1/1 pieces (100.00%) [0/0] with 0/1 peers at 0.00/0.00 kB/s.
```

Порт 7816 открыт как на клиенте, который загружает, так и на VDS-сервере.

---

Вопрос: почему не работает загрузка, если использовать торрент-трекер на внешнем IP-адресе и как это исправить?